# Is there a formal definition of a number theoretical statement which is self-referential?

Tags: logic, foundations, proof-theory, incompleteness

Let our structure be $(\mathbb{N};+,\times,0,1,<)$. From that structure, Kurt Godel constructed a sentence which has two meanings, a straight-forward number-theoretical meaning, and a higher-level self-referential meaning which basically says, "I am not provable in Peano Arithmetic". But, is there a rigorous definition somewhere of a number-theoretical statement which is self-referential? For example, we can all agree that "$5$ is a prime number" is not self-referential. So, has anyone proposed a formal definition of the intuitive concept of self-referential statement? Or, is this another of those things which is "you know it when you see it"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a great question! My personal take would be that there is **no fully satisfying formalization yet known**, but there also is no convincing argument yet that no such formalization can exist. Incidentally, I strongly recommend the books [*Diagonalization and self-reference* (Smullyan)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/diagonalization-and-self-reference-9780198534501?cc=us&lang=en&) and [*Self-reference and modal logic* (Smorynski)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8601-8) if you can get your hands on them (they're hard to find).

(For a variety of reasons I'm going to work over a *theory* - namely first-order Peano arithmetic $\mathsf{PA}$, although the details won't matter - rather than a *structure*; basically, this is Godelian rather than Tarskian, and is ultimately in my opinion the right way to set things up.)

---

Let's start with the following naive notion:

> Given a formula $\varphi(x)$, a sentence $\theta$ **asserts its own $\varphi$-ness** iff $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash \theta\leftrightarrow\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner}).$$ A sentence $\theta$ is **naively self-referential** iff there is some formula $\varphi$ such that $\theta$ asserts its own $\varphi$-ness.

*(Note that I'm choosing a specific Godel numbering here. We could also vary the numbering, and the question of what a "Godel numbering" really is is a great one, but to me that's a separate question so I'm punting for now.)*

Now naive self-referentiality has the nice property of being perfectly formal. However, it's also pretty boring: just take as our choice of $\varphi$ the formula $\tau_n(x)=$ "$x$ is the Godel number of a true $\Sigma_n$ sentence" for some sufficiently large $n$. (This *doesn't* contradict [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem), since a different $\tau_n$ is needed for different $n$s. Tarski just rules out a single $\tau$ doing the job for all $n$.) $\mathsf{PA}$ proves the "deflation scheme" $\eta\leftrightarrow\tau_n(\underline{\ulcorner\eta\urcorner})$ whenever $\eta$ is $\Sigma_n$, so this works.

So naive self-referentiality joins the long list of natural-at-first-but-actually-SUPER-BORING ideas in logic. But beating dead horses is great exercise, so let's not stop there. I think that naive self-referentiality is actually unsatisfying for an even deeper reason!

Specifically, I would argue the informal interpretation of $\theta$ as *being* (rather than merely *behaving as*) the natural-language sentence "I am $(\Sigma_n$-)true" is **not justified** by the mere fact that $$(*)\quad\mathsf{PA}\vdash\theta\leftrightarrow\tau_n(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner}).$$ This is because lots of other sentences *also* satisfy $(*)$ in place of $\theta$ - namely, *any* other sentence of the same (or lesser) syntactic complexity. So it seems that information is lost when we choose to construe $\theta$ as self-referential on the basis of $\tau_n$ (for sufficiently large $n$) alone.

Interestingly, a "dual" of this objection can be levied against the Godel sentence itself! This is because it turns out to be $\mathsf{PA}$-provably-equivalent to $\mathsf{Con(PA)}$, and $\mathsf{Con(PA)}$ (I would argue) doesn't have any compelling self-referential character. These two objections together motivate (in my opinion) a strengthening of naive self-reference: informally, say that $\theta$ is **irreducibly self-referential** iff for some $\varphi$ there is no $\mathsf{PA}$-meaningful difference between being $\theta$ and being a $\varphi$-fixed-point. The precise definition can be found at [this old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417499/which-sentences-are-irreducibly-self-referential-over-mathsfpa), asking whether the notion is in fact nontrivial. Sadly, that question is open, and the initial optimism I had has long since faded: I now suspect that either every sentence is irreducibly self-referential, or only the $\mathsf{PA}$-decidable sentences are irreducibly self-referential, and neither of these options is interesting.

Going back to naive self-reference, we could shift attention to *the set of ways* that a given sentence is naively self-referential instead of the simple yes/no question "is there naive self-reference at all." Specifically, for $\theta$ a sentence let $$\mathsf{NSR}(\theta)=\{\varphi: \theta\mbox{ asserts its own $\varphi$-ness}\}.$$ Maybe some $\theta$s have "larger" $\mathsf{NSR}$s than others; conversely, we could try to "weight" elements of $\mathsf{NSR}(\theta)$ based on how uniquely they pin down $\theta$ (e.g. $\tau_n\in\mathsf{NSR}(\theta)$ whenever $\theta\in\Sigma_n$, so $\tau_n$ should carry little weight in this sense). At the very least, we could look for interesting structural comparisons here. As far as I know, this is largely unexplored. But even if there's something interesting here, note that we would be unlikely to get a clean divide between "self-referential" and "non-self-referential" - rather, we'd more likely see a *spectrum* of possibilities. I've asked a question which can be thought of as a naive first step in this direction [at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436032/are-there-different-levels-of-self-referentiality-in-arithmetic).

Comment: Nice answer. As you may know, your points have interesting connections to debates about truth-conditional semantics in philosophy of language generally (e.g. Davidson, Soames). Also +1 on the Smullyan reference; it's sad that a new copy costs a small fortune.